# New Jersey early voting statistics 2021

Tags: united-states, election, data-sources, new-jersey

I typed "2021 early vote New Jersey statistics" into my search engine. I could not find any relevant results.

*Are there publicly available statistics on early voting in the 2021 New Jersey elections?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Early voting data can now be obtained from individual counties’ boards of elections, or [directly from the New Jersey Division of Elections](https://www.state.nj.us/opra/) by filing a request under the Open Public Records Act.

Alternatively, the Rebovich Institute for New Jersey Politics at Rider University [runs a blog](https://newjerseyearlyvoteupdates.blogspot.com/) which requests this data from the NJ DoE and posts the reports daily.

---

**Old answer**

Not yet, but there will be - these will be published daily by the various [county boards of elections](https://www.nj.gov/state/elections/vote-county-election-officials.shtml) during the early voting period, which for a general election lasts from the 10th calendar day before the election to the 2nd calendar day before. In the case of the 2021 general elections, this runs from October 23rd-31st.

This was provided for as part of the early voting bill signed into law in March '21:

> **[19:15A-3  Information available to the public](https://lis.njleg.state.nj.us/nxt/gateway.dll/statutes/1/19721/19964)**
>
> During each early voting period, the county board shall make available
> to the public a tally of the total number of voters who have cast a
> ballot at each early voting location during the previous day.  The
> county boards shall prepare an electronic data file listing the names
> of the individual voters who cast a ballot during the early voting
> period.  This information shall be made available to the public in an
> electronic format pursuant to rules adopted by the county board and
> subject to review each year by the Secretary of State.  The
> information shall be updated and made available to the public no later
> than noon of each day during the early voting period and shall at the
> same time be provided to the clerk of the county in which early voting
> is occurring and to the Secretary of State.